# Extract Setter Property name from SetterBase?

Tags: xaml, styles, winrt-xaml, setter

Is it possible to extract the Property Name from the SetterBase collection I get from Style class?

For example, in the code below:

```
            Style style = Application.Current.Resources[ModifierNameMinimalNoPopStyle] as Style;
            descriptionText.Style = style;
            var setterCollection = style.Setters;
```

I would like to extract what "FontFamily" the Style has and use it in my code.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could bind directly to the property if the styled control exists in the same context. Except I'm curious. Does the style have a static FontFamily or is it bound to something, or a staticresource? I would think grabbing it dynamically wouldn't normally be required.

Comment: Thanks Chris! It is a StaticResource. The setter is like this: <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do based on your response to avoid unnecessary chaining. Take that font and make it into an actual `StaticResource` by plopping it into your ResourceDictionary like;

```
<FontFamily x:Key="SpecialFont">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
```

Then it's available everywhere, and if you ever need to change it then you have only one spot to do it at where it will propagate to every instance via inheritance by for example changing your Setter from;

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
```

to;

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SpecialFont}" />
```

Now if you need it anywhere else you can actually grab it as a StaticResource from the same static location, as example;

```
<Button FontFamily="{StaticResource SpecialFont}" Content="I'm Segoe UI Font"/>
```

or code behind;

```
this.btn.SetResourceReference(FontFamilyProperty, "SpecialFont");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I will give this a try.

Comment: Hi Chris, yup worked for me. Sorry was pretty busy. Thanks!